# DocuSign SDK ViewUrl not opening on web server but is ok on local IIS in VS2015

Tags: sdk, docusignapi

I am creating a custom integration for DocuSign.  The user opens a web page that builds a document from data it's collected and then opens a new page for the DocuSign site.  The document is matched to a template and asks the user to confirm.

The issue is that the code works fine on my local IIS server in Visual Studio 2015, however when it's published to our production web server the window never opens.

Here are the lines of code that do the work:

```
ViewUrl senderView = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(DSConfig.AccountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, options);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(senderView.Url);
```

I am referencing DocuSign.eSign.Api and DocuSign.eSign.Model.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Upon review of the code and discussion with our web administrator, I changed the code from using this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(senderView.Url);
```

to this:

```
Response.Redirect(senderView.Url);
```

Since I'm already in a web page, it was a more logical alternative.  Hope this helps someone else out there!